# Make default attribute for Model in October CMS

Tags: php, forms, models, backend, octobercms

I'm making a backend Ajax form action in Controller.

```
$this->asExtension('FormController')->create_onSave();
```

In the *field.yaml* file there are 4 fields, and all their values go perfectly, validation works.
In the database I need to pass a fifth value: *theme*, that is just the current active theme, so I don't want to show it on the page.
The problem starts when I'm trying to add it in Model with:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->attributes['theme'] = Theme::getActiveThemeCode();
}
```

After adding this method in Model, all 5 values go to the database, but they skip validation, so in the database I can add empty values. What is causing this to go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to assign the value to the property in the current instance instead of try to overwrite the raw values.

```php
public function beforeSave()
{
  $this->theme = Theme::getActiveThemeCode();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, That's the only solution